# react native how to custom style with props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to make a custom button component and change the style of the button using props. Below is my code:

```
class CustomButton extends React.Component {

render() {

    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
      style={{height:this.props.height, borderWidth:1}}>

      <Text style={{fontSize:13}}>{this.props.text}</Text>

      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}
}
```

And I call my component like this:

```
<CustomButton

      // custom text using props works fine
      text="whatever I want to say"

      // But changing custom style won't work.
     height='200' or 200
/>
```

I am able to change the `text` using props however, when I apply the same to change the `height` it won't work. How could I change the style using props?

Comment: Do you want 30 to be the default height?

Comment: I made a mistake I edited `height:30`

Comment: @vlaz u tell me

Comment: @kirimi you had the `Java` tag on your but it didn't seem like it was related to Java. I don't know enough about your problem to accurately tell if that's true or not - perhaps you are using Java for some aspect of your app that's related to this code but that isn't readily apparent. Or perhaps not and you thought Java and JavaScript are somehow related. I wanted to clear the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
<CustomButton
  text="whatever you want to say" 
  height={200}
/>
```

hope it works

Comment: Yea I just figured it out too! Just putting `{}` make it works! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not enough points to comment, can you try sending

```
<CustomButton
  text="....."
  height='200px'
/>
```

The reason being the style is expecting 200px as height px being one of the key metric.
There are other metrics such as px, em, vw, etc [check w3 units for css](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)

Comment: is it possible for you to share the whole portion in a jsfiddle? I just checked on https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity, looks fine there.

Comment: @ kunkyab thanks for the comments. I get an error saying that `JSON value '200' of type NSString cannot be converted to a YGValue. DId you forget the % or pt suffix?` If I put `%` error is gone but result is not what I want.

Comment: I just gave this a shot (https://jsfiddle.net/rx3x2bqf/21/) the props `yolo` is going through, and just to be able to see the changes, I add a background color. when I don't add the px to the '200' I get a warning "react.js:19500 Warning: a `div` tag (owner: `Counter`) was passed a numeric string value for CSS property `height` (value: `200`) which will be treated as a unitless number in a future version of React."

Comment: Just saw the correct answer. Kind of bumped I didn't think of that.. :| Thanks @kirimi for entertaining me.